# Any idea what is causing the slight movement at the top of the image when hovering?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I have the following HTML:

```
<figure>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" alt="">
  <figcaption>This is the caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

And the following CSS:

```
figure {
  background: #ddd;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 50px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
figure:hover img {
  box-shadow: 0 30px 20px -10px hsla(0,0%,0%,.25);
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(45deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
}
img {
  position: relative;
  transition: .2s;
  vertical-align: top;
  z-index: 10;
}
figcaption {
  bottom: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Here is a live example: http://codepen.io/joshnh/pen/FlvJr

Despite setting the `transform-origin` to the top of the image, it still moves down slightly when hovering. What is causing this, and how do I prevent it?

Comment: I think what's happening (although I'm no expert on this) is that you are rotating it 45degrees and then readjusting the location, so for that split second while the animation is rotating the picture, you will not be at the top. I think what has to happen is that the picture needs to be aligned dynamically during the animation. I'm not sure how to do this, so I'm not counting it as a solution. I'm just throwing a thought out there to get other people thinking. Is there a way to rotate the image by the top of the image instead of by the center (which I think is what's happening)?

Comment: It moves down, but moves back up. Remove the transition rule and you won't see the jump. I guess it's just the way it is.

Comment: @bspymaster As I am explicitly telling the image to rotate about its topmost point, by using `transform-origin`, there is no readjustment of location. So I am actually doing what you are proposing.

Comment: @bspymaster it is aligning by the top of the image. That's what the origin rule is for. Take it out and you'll see it rotating around the center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/cQphE/

The problem was that you were transitioning, along with the `transform` property, the `transform-origin`. On hover it was going from the default `50% 50%` to the `50% 0;` you set.

You have this:

```
img {
  transition: 0.2s;
}

figure:hover img {
  box-shadow: 0 30px 20px -10px hsla(0,0%,0%,.25);
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(45deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
}
```

Which is the same as having this:

```
img {
  box-shadow: none;
  transform: perspective(0) rotateX(0);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

figure:hover img {
  box-shadow: 0 30px 20px -10px hsla(0,0%,0%,.25);
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(45deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
}
```

What you should have is this:

```
img {
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

figure:hover img {
  box-shadow: 0 30px 20px -10px hsla(0,0%,0%,.25);
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(45deg);
}
```

Comment: Right. That makes sense now. So basically, what happens is that you are seeing the _completed_ animation set its origin to the top, whereas what you want to do is set the image's origin to the top _before_ the transformation. Am I correct?

Comment: I made some changes to your code, as there were a couple of errors, but all-in-all, this is the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, exactly. I think youve got it.